# Writing out numbers in ranges: between 5 and 50 or between five and 50?

Tags: phd, thesis

In a manuscript, when defining a specific range that starts below ten and ends bigger than ten, is it written as numerals for all, for the number below ten or all in numerals?

Example:

> We detected between 5 and 58 genes.

or

> We detected between five and 58 genes.

Previous discussions on this topic don't really answer this specific case
[When and why should you write numbers less than 10 in words?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/when-and-why-should-you-write-numbers-less-than-10-in-words)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a question about English language and usage ...

Comment: Or “between five and fifty “...

Comment: For measured values, you should use "5 and 58". For enumerations "five to fifty reasons"

Comment: @virmaior why is this off-topic but the linked question not?

Comment: Okay alternately that question contains your answer.

Comment: No answer in the linked thread discusses this topic. Stop being pedantic. Thank you for answering my question. If you had done so as an answer and not a comment, I would have marked it as accepted.

Comment: I agree with the OP - if the linked question is on-topic, so should this one.

Comment: For the sake of consistency, you have one more choice: "We detected between five and fifty-eight  genes". I personally prefer your first one , i.e. "We detected between 5 and 58 genes" Consistent, concise and clear.